# Adding text to a 'paragraph' containing an image using python docx

Tags: python, image, syntax, formatting, python-docx

I'm using python docx which claims in the documentation that:

> 'Often, a picture is placed in a paragraph by itself, but this is not required. It can have text before and after it in the paragraph in which it’s placed.'

But I cant find out how to do this, could someone explain (idealy with a basic example) how I get text before the image while in the same paragraph please. So the line of text ends with an image.

I've not found any answers to this but have seen people asking the same elsewhere with no solution.

Thanks 
(note: I'm not a hugely experiance programmer and other than this awkward part the rest of my code will very basic)

Comment: Does this example do what you have in mind?  https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, `python-docx` doesn't have the features to support what you're trying to do.

The feature that *would* support it would be `Run.add_picture()`. If you add a feature request to the [python-docx issue tracker](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues), I'll see how soon we can get to it.

In the meantime, if you wanted to dig in and see what you could hack up, I'd recommend starting here, at [`Document.add_picture`](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/api.py#L75), as the structure would be analogous and use mostly the same calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to write docx files with Python, you can use another module:
https://github.com/rafaels88/py2docx